# How many records does Oracle 10g Express Edition allow?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

how many records does Oracle 10g Express Edition allow?

Comment: Do you mean Oracle Database 10g Express Edition?

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 -

Answer (score 6):

It will store up to 4GB of user data. I don't believe there is a limitation on the number of records.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/dbxe-faq-129842.pdf

Answer (score -4):

**An oracle 10g / 11g table is capable of storing 300 million records in it including picture,audio and video.**